# Does the function $f(x) = |x|e^x$ have a derivative at $x = 0$?

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, derivatives

Does the function $f(x) \ = \ |x|e^x$ have a derivative at $x = 0$?

If we split it into two sides

$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
xe^x,  & \text{if $\geq 0$} \\
-xe^x, & \text{if $x<0$}
\end{cases}
$$
& 
$$f'(x) =
\begin{cases}
(x+1)e^x,  & \text{if $x \geq 0$} \\
-(x+1)e^x, & \text{if $x<0$}
\end{cases}
$$
so

$\lim\limits_{x \to 0^+} \ (x+1)e^x = 1$,

and

$\lim\limits_{x \to 0^-} \ -(x+1)e^x = -1$

so we can say that the function doesn't have derivative a derivative at zero? Is this correct?

Comment: Note: it is possible (but not true in this case) that a function $f$ can be differentiable at $0$ but $\lim_{x \to 0} f'(x)$ does not exist.  Therefore, the answer of Martin R is better than your method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct that the function does not have a derivative at $x = 0$.  Since the derivative of $xe^x, x \geq 0$ is defined in the open interval $(0, \infty)$ and the derivative of $-xe^x, x < 0$ is defined in the open interval $(-\infty, 0)$, we cannot write 
$$f'(x) = 
\begin{cases}
(x + 1)e^x & \text{if $x \color{red}{\geq} 0$}\\
-(x + 1)e^x & \text{if $x < 0$}
\end{cases}
$$
What you should have written is 
$$f'(x) = 
\begin{cases}
(x + 1)e^x & \text{if $x > 0$}\\
-(x + 1)e^x & \text{if $x < 0$}
\end{cases}
$$
then tested the left- and right-sided limits, as you later did, to determine whether $f'(0)$ exists.

Comment: But why we cant write x>=0? I did not get it

Comment: @sam0101  You established that $f'(0)$ does not exist.  However, writing $f'(x) = (x + 1)e^x$ if $x \geq 0$ implies that it does exist.  Moreover, you are further asserting that $f'(0) = 1$.  More generally, when you are testing whether the derivative of a piecewise-defined function exists at a point where the definition of the function changes, you take the derivative in each open interval, then compare the limits of the left- and right-sided derivatives at the point.  The derivative only exists at that point is the left- and right-sided derivatives exist and their limits agree at that point.

Comment: I get it now, thank you

Comment: The derivative at 0, if exists, is not necessarily the same as the limit of the derivative. What he should test is the equality of left and right limits of the incremental ratio.

Answer (score 8):

$f$ is not differentiable at $x=0$ because
$$
 \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} = \frac{|x|e^x}{x} =
\begin{cases}
e^x & \text{if $x > 0$}\\
-e^x & \text{if $x < 0$}
\end{cases}
$$
does not have a limit for $x \to 0$.

It is not necessary to compute $f'(x)$ for $x\ne 0$ in order to draw this conclusion, or to investigate
its limit behavior at $x=0$. And actually the implication
$$
 \lim_{x \to 0}f'(x) \text{ does not exist } \implies
 \text{ $f$  is not differentiable at $x=0$ }
$$
is wrong, as the following example shows:
$$
 f(x) = \begin{cases}
x^2 \cos(\frac 1x) & \text{if $x \ne 0$}\\
0 & \text{if $x = 0$}
\end{cases}
$$

It is however true that if $f'(x)$ has both left-sided limit and
right-sided limit at $x=0$, and if those one-sided limits are different,
then $f'(0)$ does not exist. That follows e.g. from the
[“intermediate value property for derivatives.”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis))
But again: it is not needed here.

Comment: This is a crisp answer.  +1

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ were differentiable at $0$, then so would $f(x)e^{-x} = |x|$ be. That's a contradiction, though.

Answer (score 0):

The function is not differentiable at $x=0$ because the right derivative is $1$ while the left derivative is $-1$.

However, the function is continuous at  $x=0$ thus it is a good example of a continuous function which is not differentiable at a point.